# Apache FTP embedded server to listen from specific IP

Tags: java, ftp

I have a machine with few IP addresses.

I want the listener to listen only from specific IP.

For example:

If I have 2 IPs on the machine, 10.10.10.10 and 10.10.10.11, and I want only the first one to listen to port 21.

If the second IP is being scanned for open port, I don't want port 21 to be opened.

Is it possible?

The current configuration cause port 21 to be opened for all IPs:

```
FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();

ListenerFactory listenerFactory = new ListenerFactory();
listenerFactory.setPort(port);
serverFactory.addListener("default", listenerFactory.createListener());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to do it...

```
FtpServerFactory serverFactory = new FtpServerFactory();

ListenerFactory listenerFactory = new ListenerFactory();
listenerFactory.setPort(port);
listenerFactory.setServerAddress("10.10.10.10");
serverFactory.addListener("default", listenerFactory.createListener());
```

Now 10.10.10.10 listens on port 21, but 10.10.10.11 doesn't.